# Ruby output in gmail has different format

Tags: email, output

```
def email_for_task_release_data(server,from,recipients,subject,body)
  puts "Sending Email"
  mailer = ModokMailer.new(from)
  recipients.each do |to|
  mailer.add_recipients(to)
  end
  mailer.add_subject(subject)
  mailer.add_body(body)
  mailer.send(server)
end

results_acunote_1.each do |row|
    body += "#{row['rel_type']}\t\t#{row['us']}\t#{row['uk']}\t#{row['jv']}\t#{row['ca']}\t    #{row['au']}\t\t #{row['total']}\n"
```

Email output vs output displayed on terminal using puts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Lyg.png)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Reda -I am trying to send an email with the output. In gmail (or mac mail or outlook), the formatting is changed even though the formatting is correct when output is displayed in terminal using puts. I am looking for a solution where formatting is not affected irrespective of the email client